# Handling events for mouse click and keydown or keypress (for non-modifier keys)

Tags: javascript, events, click, combinations, keypress

I am new to JS and trying to learn on my own - thanks for any help!

I am trying to have a simple program respond to a click differently depending on what other key is pressed at the time of the mouse click.

I have searched far and wide and have not been able to find an answer that works for non-modifier keys alt and shift (which I have had no trouble implementing).  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to achieve the same result with a regular character key.

[The example below (which I found in other comments on this site)](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Du7rQ/) works if the alt key is employed.

```
<div id="targetDiv">I want to put a ding in the universe.</div>

$(function() {
  $("#targetDiv").click(function(event) {
    if (event.altKey) {
       //do something, alt was down when clicked
    }
  });
});
```

However, the intuitive modification does not work.

For example, the otherwise identical code (now using event.keyCode===114) does not work **(?!)** when the 'r' key is pressed (nor does event.charCode===114 do the trick):

```
 <div id="targetDiv">I want to put a ding in the universe.</div>
    $(function() {
          $("#targetDiv").click(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode===114) {
               //do something, alt was down when clicked
            }
          });
        });
```

What went wrong?

I am able to get functionality out of a keyPress if I listen to it alone:

```
addEventListener("keypress", rIsPressed, false);

function rIsPressed(event){
    if(event.keyCode===114){    
    console.log("the 'r' key is pressed");
    }
}
```

however nothing seems to work when I try to pair a character keypress with a mouse click or even a character keypress with a modifier keypress:

```
addEventListener("keypress", rIsPressed, false);

function rIsPressed(event){
    if((event.keyCode===114) && (event.altKey)){    
    console.log("the 'alt' and 'r' keys are pressed");
    }
}
```

Note: I have tried keydown instead of keypress in all of these examples with no success.

Suggestions please on what I am missing or overlooking - what is problematic about pairing a character key down/press with a modifier key or a mouse click !?

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm checking out right now, but my guess is that the click event doesn't have a `keyCode` property, so doing `event.keyCode` in your click function won't work

Comment: just threw an example together in vs, the click event does not have a `keyCode` property so doing `event.keyCode===114` isn't going to work

Comment: you could do something like have the click event and the button press set a flag with a timestamp and whichever event happens first checks to see if the flag was set within a short enough amount of time.  Not the best solution but it would work

Comment: the timestamp is a property of the click event so that wouldn't be hard to impliment, `event.timestamp`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I commented above, the click event does not have a property called `keyCode` so doing `event.keyCode` will not work.  The only reason that control and alt work is because they are properties of the click event, `event.ctrlKey` and `event.altKey`.  You can be a little more creative and use something like this maybe though I don't really know what you need:

```
var currKey = null;

$("#targetDiv").click(function (event) {
    if (currKey != null) {
        $("#targetDiv").text(currKey);
    }
});
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    currKey = event.which;
});
$(window).keyup(function (event) {
    currKey = null;
});
```

This stores the key code when keydown is fired, when keyup is fired it clears the var.  The stuff in the click event is only allowed to run if the var shows something other than null.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - I would have been chasing that information forever on my own.

Your solution seems like it will work very well for what I am trying to do and your explanation will be very helpful in general as I continue to learn to code.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, debuggers are your friend!  If you break the code in the click event you can see what properties it has, and doesn't have.  If this solution worked for you I'd appreciate it if you accepted this answer.

Comment: Ill try it out and see how it works - although it may still take me a while to get it built in to my code.

Also, I have no idea what you mean by debuggers - but, given your enthusiasm, it seems like I should ask?  Do you mean something other than opening up the console panel when the code is run?

I would be happy to up-vote your question, but I am new to the site and dont have that priveledge yet!

Comment: A debugger is something used to pause execution of code so that you can look at values.  If you hit f12 in most modern browsers you'll get some way to look at the js code loaded (ie it's called, "debugger", chrome it's called "code" if I remember correctly).  If you click next to a line number it'll put in a red dot there and when the page loads next it'll stop there and you can look at variables and objects.  If you use Visual Studio or some other tool you can do the same thing as you edit the file!  Debuggers are extremely powerful tools for discovering why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds like it would certainly be helpful - Ill check it out.

I had to poke at it for a really long time, but I eventually figured out how to get your code to work with mine.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: and it looks like my up-voting privileges finally got authorized !